# Reset conda root directory?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I recently switched mac computers. My old computer had conda and all the relevant libraries and environments installed. I transferred all the files from the old computer to my new one. However, my new computer has a different username (home directory name) than the old one, so whenever I run conda commands, I get errors like the following:

```
__conda_exe:2: no such file or directory: /Users/[old_username]/anaconda/bin/conda
```

I can circumvent this initial error by manually setting $PATH each time, but then I still get errors like this:

```
__add_sys_prefix_to_path:6: command not found: dirname
__add_sys_prefix_to_path:7: command not found: dirname
__conda_exe:2: no such file or directory: /Users/[old_username]/anaconda/bin/conda
```

Is there a way to change this so the commands point to my new home directory?

Comment: Make sure you append/prepend like `export PATH="$PATH;/Users/tobykrieman/anaconda/bin/conda"` instead of overriding, because it usually contain a list of directories.

Comment: I know I have already done that, but I still get these errors

Comment: Restart your terminal and try again. I also made a typo in my comment. `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/tobykrieman/anaconda/bin/conda"`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use [`CPR` (conda-prefix-replacement)](https://github.com/conda/conda-prefix-replacement) for this.

However, I'd instead recommend *not* manually transferring the files, since this usually fails to retain hardlinks. Instead, dump each of your environments to YAML

```
conda env export -n envname > env.yaml
```

and recreate them on the new system (after a minimal **base** install, like Miniconda)

```
conda env create -n envname -f env.yaml
```

I would not recommend transferring the old **base**, but if you must, put it in a new location:

```
# old system
conda env export -n base > old_base.yaml

# new system
conda env create -n old_base -f old_base.yaml
```